# Is my hotel database design right?

Tags: database, database-design

I'm designing an hotel database structure. What is the correct way of doing database design ? This is my current DB structure, is it right ?

**Main table**
**HOTELS TABLE VER**

```
htl_pk_id   PK
htl_name    
htl_slug    
htl_description 
htl_surroundings    
htl_services    
htl_stars   
htl_ratings 
htl_is_featured 
htl_featured_from   
htl_featured_to 
htl_owned_by    
htl_type    
htl_basic_price 
htl_basic_discount  
htl_address 
htl_pin_code    
htl_city_id 
htl_state_id    
htl_country_id  
htl_latitude    
htl_latitude    
htl_meta_title  
htl_meta_keywords   
htl_meta_desc   
 htl_amenities  
htl_payment_opt 
htl_total_floors    
htl_total_rooms 
htl_max_adults  
htl_max_children    
htl_check_in    
htl_check_out   
htl_policy  
htl_is_enabled  
htl_order   
htl_related_hotels  
htl_comm_fixed  
htl_comm_percentage 
htl_tax_fixed   
 htl_tax_percentage 
htl_email   
htl_phone   
htl_website 
htl_featured_forever    
htl_is_trusted  
 htl_is_refundable  
 thumbnail_image    
htl_created_at
```

**tables after decomposing above table**

**HOTELS TABLE VER 2**

```
htl_pk_id   PK
htl_name    
htl_slug    
htl_description 
htl_stars   
htl_ratings 
htl_owner_id    
htl_type    
htl_basic_price 
htl_basic_discount  
htl_payment_opt 
htl_list_sort_order 
htl_comm_fixed  
htl_comm_percentage 
htl_tax_fixed   
htl_tax_percentage  
htl_is_trusted  
htl_is_refundable   
thumbnail_image 
htl_created_at  
htl_is_enabled
```

**HOTELS FEATURED TABLE VER**

```
htl_fturd_pk_id PK                       
htl_fturd_htl_fk_id FK            
htl_fturd_is_featured_forever     
htl_fturd_is_featured        
htl_featured_from            
htl_featured_to
```

**HOTELS ADDRESSES**

```
htl_adrs_pk_id  PK                       
htl_adrs_htl_fk_id  FK                      
htl_adrs_address                          
htl_adrs_pin_code                         
htl_adrs_city_id                          
htl_adrs_state_id                         
htl_adrs_country_id
```

**HOTELS GOOGLE MAP LOCATIONS**

```
htl_ggle_pk_id  PK                      
htl_ggle_htl_fk_id  FK                      
htl_ggle_address_on_map                       
htl_ggle_latitude                         
htl_ggle_longitude
```

**HOTELS META DATA**

```
htl_mt_dt_pk_id PK                      
htl_mt_dt_htl_fk_id FK                      
htl_mt_title                          
htl_mt_keywords                       
htl_mt_description
```

**HOTELS CAPACITIES**

```
htl_cpct_pk_id  PK                      
htl_cpct_htl_fk_id  FK                      
htl_cpct_total_floors                         
htl_cpct_total_rooms                          
htl_cpct_max_adults                       
htl_cpct_max_children
```

**HOTELS POLICIES**

```
htl_plc_pk_id   PK                      
htl_plc_htl_fk_id   FK                      
htl_plc_policy                        
htl_plc_check_in                          
htl_plc_check_out
```

**HOTELS CONTACTS**

```
htl_cntct_pk_id PK                       
htl_cntct_htl_fk_id FK                      
htl_cntct_email                       
htl_cntct_phone                       
htl_cntct_website
```

Comment: Hello sagarraj, welcome to SO! Please check out the [documentation about asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You should edit your question to make it minimal and clear for everyone. What do you mean by decomposing database ? Also make the title as clear and short as possible.

Comment: i am designing database for hotel reservation . i have designed above database first table is hotels after doing normalization remaining tables was created.  i am asking is that above design is correct or wrong

Comment: Because you are a new user, I edited your post to show you how it could have been improved. It will be visible when it will have been reviewed. Next time you will be able to do it.

Comment: thanks for your valuable help